# VBA : Transfer Data Automatically from One Worksheet to Another If condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to copy data from one Worksheet to another if a given condition is met.

I was trying to use the following code :

```
Sub CopyPoe()
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range



Set StatusCol = Tabelle2.Range("G2:G260")


For Each Status In StatusCol
    If Tabelle3.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Tabelle15.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Tabelle15.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    If Status = "Yes" Then Status.Offset(0, -6).Resize(25, 24).Copy PasteCell

Next Status


End Sub
```

The Problem I have is that it gives everything out not just the cells with "yes" in them.

Does anybody has a solution ?

Comment: you are resizing the copy range to 25 rows.  It should probably be: `Resize(1, 24)`

Comment: That only gives me one Row, what i want is ever row that contains "Yes" in the column G

Comment: You are looping each row.  It will grab each that says yes, one row at a time.  with it being 25 you are grabbing 25 rows at a time.

Comment: I understand that, but I only get one row as output. I want every row with "Yes" in column G to be displayed in the Worksheet that i am copying to.

Comment: is A being populated or is it empty.  My guess is that A is empty on the rows being copied in and therefore you keep overwriting the data.

Comment: Also look into Range.Filter to filter on the `Yes` and then use Range.SpecialCells to copy only the visible and paste the whole in one go.  It will be quicker than iterating a range.